# The summation of piecewise functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a piecewise function `F_m(x)` as below, where `x_m` and `\alpha` are constants, `m` is the subscript.

[image: piecewise function]

I need to solve the following equation that involves `F_m(x)`, where `N` and `C` are constants, `tau` is the variable I want to solve.

[image: equation]

So I resort this question to Matlab. First I write an function in a .m file:

```
function y=pareto_CDF(x, xm)
    alpha = 2; %set alpha to 2

    if x < xm
        y = 0;
    else
        y = 1-(xm/x)^alpha;
    end
```

Then in another .m file I write:

```
syms x;
C = 1000;       
N = 20000;      

%Pareto Distribution CDF: F(x)=1-(xm/x)^alpha. 
%alpha is set to 2 in this program

alpha = 2;

j=1:1:N;
f=sum(pareto_CDF(x, 1/(alpha*rand())));


a = f - C;
tau = solve(a,'x');
```

However, I got the following error from Matlab when running it:

```
Conversion to logical from sym is not possible.

Error in pareto_CDF (line 4)
    if x < xm
```

The problem now is: I need to declare `x` as `sym` because it is the variable in the equation, since I invoke `pareto_CDF(x, xm)`, the `x` in this function is also `sym`, but Matlabt does not support the comparison between a `sym` and a value (xm). This error actually stems from the piecewise nature of function `F(x)`.

So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Congratulations for your piecewise function! I have a deribable function and a matrix!

Comment: no joke please, I am having trouble editing latex. I put $ sign on both sides of the function, but it seems not work now.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not have latex support. The joke was because you just didn't even ask a question. You just stated that you have a piecewise function.

Comment: I became aware of the latex problem before I can finish the question.

Comment: Then I apologise for the joke. Please, use an online  equation editor to create an image and post it. And finish the question before, just in case people close you question because is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Using `heaviside()` function resolves my problem. Rewrite the function .m file as follows:

```
function y=pareto_CDF(x, xm)
    alpha = 2; %set alpha to 2

    y = heaviside(x-xm).*(1-(xm/x).^alpha);
```

The reason I use element-by-element product/division (.*, ./) is because the input may be a vector.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing pareto_CDF such that it takes vector as input and returns vector as output:

```
xm = 4;
% test with scalar x
pareto_CDF( 1, xm ) % => 0
pareto_CDF( 6, xm ) % => 0.556

% test with vector x
pareto_CDF( [1,6] , xm ) => [0, 0.556]

end

function y = pareto_CDF(x, xm)
alpha = 2; %set alpha to 2

y = 1-(xm./x).^alpha;
y( x < xm ) = 0;

end
```

Comment: does vector make any difference?

Comment: yes, thus you don't need to declare x as sym and you can do:

    `sum(pareto_CDF( [1,6] , xm ))`